# Consistent shebangs

Tags: python, executable, shebang

I am trying to create an executable python script for use on the command line (aim is to upload to PyPi). For this I need to add a shebang.

- On linux I have `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
- For windows I need `#! python3`

How do I get the appropriate shebang for the different OS's?

Side note: I looked at an example of an executable file (cookiecutter) I have in a conda environment. I noticed the shebang was

```
#!/home/<my-name>/miniconda/envs/<some-environment>/bin/python3.6
```

Is Conda do something smart here? What about pip?

Comment: What are you using for installation of your script? Anything using `setup.py` already [replaces a shebang containing the word "python" with an installer-specified path](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts), so you the author don't have to worry about something that is only of concern to the end user.

Comment: To be clear, *don't* assume the script should be run with whatever Python is in the user's path, which is what `/usr/bin/env python3` does. Maybe your user doesn't use Python 2 at all and doesn't use `python3` as the name of the Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: Your `/home/...` shebang is an example; when installing into your virtual environment, the shebang was replaced with the path to the Python binary belonging to that virtual env.

Comment: @chepner That’s frankly on the user. `python3` is the default and recommended name of the interpreter, and *some version of it* should be in the user’s path if the user has Python 3 installed. I know some POSIX OS does it differently by default (forgot which) but … eh.

Comment: Default according to whom? Anyway, the point is, the *author* is not supposed to worry about the location of the interpreter; that's for the *installer* to decide, and that's what Python (all the way back to `distutils`) supports.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You're thinking of ArchLinux (maybe others, but most have stuck to `python3`).

Comment: @chepner According to the PSF. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/

Answer (score 2):

The Linux shebang [works just fine on Windows with modern versions of Python and its dedicated `py.exe` launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/#shebang-line-parsing). Just use the Linux shebang consistently. Conda's shebang is designed to launch a very specific Python installation; in general, you want to use the default up-to-date Python 3 install, and the `PATH` lookup approach on Linux (and emulation on Windows) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

use [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) `console_scripts` feature.

It will generate the shebang for you